# Specifying the timezone of a date in the WHERE clause of a Postgres SQL query

Tags: postgresql, datetime

In Postgres, I always store my dates using timestamp with time zone.

For the sake of the discussion, let assume I have to store events at the time (8am, 1pm and 10pm) in Eastern Time Zone (EST -04) on the 2018-01-16.  The timestamp in the database would be :

> - 8 am: "2018-01-16 12:00:00.000+00"
> - 1 pm: "2018-01-16 17:00:00.000+00"
> - 10pm: "2018-01-17 02:00:00.000+00"

How would I write a Postgres SQL query to get all events that occurred on the 2018-01-16 EST?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `AT TIME ZONE` construct is your friend:

```
WHERE CAST((tscol AT TIME ZONE 'EST') AS date) = DATE '2018-01-16'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT fields, stamp FROM table WHERE stamp < '2018-01-16T00:00:00.000-04:00'
```

PostgreSQL accepts ISO 8601 format and standard SQL format.

You can also use `=`, `<=`, `=`, `>=`, `>` and `BETWEEN`, which is inclusive.

Comment: wait, is BETWEEN inclusive? can you make sure of it? since actually i have tried many times that the same date for date_from and date_to column WITHOUT time for BETWEEN, it doesn't show any result from the table that has records in that specific date

Comment: @farisfath25 `"X BETWEEN ASYMMETRIC Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z"`. The SYMMTETRIC/ASYMMETRIC keyword support is optional, and default is ASYMMETRIC. [SQL-1999](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~len/sql1999.pdf) page 295 (321 in print). [SQL-1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) `"X BETWEEN Y AND Z" is equivalent to "X>=Y AND X<=Z"`

Comment: i see, thanks for the information with resource. i think i made some mistake in my query then

Comment: additionally, yeah, i just checked the postgre official doc in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html, it said the same (edit: changed url)